# hyperledger composer network update

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is anyone have an idea why composer network update is not listed to available commands for composer network? is it already deprecated? If yes, what is the substitute command for it? Thanks in advance.

composer network

Composer network command

Commands:
  composer network download [options]  Downloads a business network from the Hyperledger Fabric, does not undeploy
  composer network install [options]   Installs a business network archive to Hyperledger Fabric
  composer network list [options]      List the contents of a business network
  composer network loglevel [options]  Change the logging level of a business network
  composer network ping [options]      Test a connection to a business network
  composer network reset [options]     Resets a business network
  composer network start [options]     Starts a specific version of a business network that is already installed to Hyperledger Fabric
  composer network upgrade [options]   Upgrades to a specific version of a business network that is already installed to Hyperledger Fabric

Options:
  --help         Show help  [boolean]
  -v, --version  Show version number  [boolean]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In composer version .19 they changed the command for update.

After changing you files change the version in `package.json`. Then use the below command to upgrade :

```
composer network upgrade -c CARD-NAME -n NETWORK-NAME -V NETWORK-VERSION
```

Comment: I already did that, but seems like that command doesn't work if it is a new .qry file. I have got to make it work by manually adding the file in composer playground. And then used the composer network upgrade command every time I modify the file in my machine and it works for me. I don't know if it is a bug of upgrade cmd or it just unfortunate for me that it didn't work if file is new.

Comment: U need to create bna a file then u need to install that bna to peers then u need to upgrade.
1. composer archive create -a file-name.bna -t dir -n .
 2.composer network install -a NETWORK-FILENAME.bna -c Card-Name
 3.composer network upgrade -c Card -n NETWORK-NAME -V NETWORK-VERSION

Answer (score 0):

Update was removed starting with composer 0.19.0 when we defined business networks as actual fabric chaincode affording it the security and management that fabric provides around chaincode.

Information about how to upgrade deployed business networks can be found here

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/upgrading-bna